# Output formatting in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to get the list of files generated on current date in the `ls -l` format using `find` command , like below:

`find . -type f -name "sample[0-9]*?_bill[0-9]*?.pdf" -mtime 0 -exec ls -l {} \;`

The output of the above command is:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 17843 Aug 20 08:02 ./sample32_bill45.pdf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 17840 Aug 20 08:02 ./sample80_bill46.pdf
```

The expected output:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 17843 Aug 20 08:02  sample32_bill45.pdf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 17840 Aug 20 08:02  sample80_bill46.pdf
```

I'm unable to figure out how to remove the `./` part from the 9th column of the output, so that i should get the desired output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I tried to solve this with `find` command itself couldn't get an option it is still showing `./` in output yet, adding `awk` with `find` command now.

```
find  -type f -name "sample[0-9]*?_bill[0-9]*?.pdf" -mtime 0 -exec ls -l {} \+ | awk '{sub("./","",$NF)} 1'
```

OR(if your files have spaces in their names you could use following then)

```
find  -type f -name "sample[0-9]*?_bill[0-9]*?.pdf" -mtime 0 -exec ls -l {} \+ | awk '{sub("./","")} 1'
```

Output will be as follows(sample/dummy files)

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 singh singh 0 Aug 20 04:08 sample32_bill4524242424.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 singh singh 0 Aug 20 04:08 sample32_bill452424.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 singh singh 0 Aug 20 04:08 sample32_bill45.pdf
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since glob which is used `sample[0-9]*?_bill[0-9]*?.pdf` which is NOT catching file name with spaces(which I tested by creating a dummy file named `sample 32_bill 4524242424.pdf`), I am adding here an answer in case anybody wants to get all file details which are only starting with string `sample` and file names could have spaces in their names then following may help here(thanks to tripleee sir who mentioned in comment section of this answer).

```
find  -type f -name "sample*" -mtime 0 -exec ls -l {} \+ | awk 'match($0,/.*\.\//){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}'

OR

find  -type f -name "sample*" -mtime 0 -exec ls -l {} \+ | sed 's%\./%%'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 singh singh 0 Aug 20 04:47 sample 32_bill 4524242424.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 singh singh 0 Aug 20 04:08 sample32_bill4524242424.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 singh singh 0 Aug 20 04:08 sample32_bill452424.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 singh singh 0 Aug 20 04:08 sample32_bill45.pdf
```

Comment: This will fail if the file names could contain spaces. They obviously don't in this scenario, but perhaps point out this caveat in case future visitors try to use this code

Comment: @tripleee, sure thank you for letting know, when I just tested it seems OP's REGEX `ample[0-9]*?_bill[0-9]*?.pdf` is NOT catching file name `sample 32_bill 4524242424.pdf`, so we should be good here, though I will add a warning too, kindly do let me know if some more suggestions sir.

Comment: @tripleee, added EDIT solution with details, 2nd solution should catch file names with spaces too.

Comment: Hmmm, a simple `sed 's%\./%%'` would fix that equivalently.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It is not matching the filename with spaces **you** used, but it will match for example: `sample1 2_bill3 4.pdf`. Remember, it's a glob, not a regex.

Comment: @tripleee, sure thanks for letting know added it now too in solution.

Comment: @PesaThe, sure thanks for letting me know, corrected it. Yes, I added `sample*` glob in my 2nd answer so even file is having spaces it should catch those names now.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 My point was that the glob `-name "sample[0-9]*?_bill[0-9]*?.pdf"` will match for example `sample1 2_bill3 4.pdf` :) In other words, that it also matches filenames with spaces.

Comment: @PesaThe, sure, added OR solution too now, which will simply remove `./` as discussed in above comments too from the line itself, please do let me know if any more suggestions :)

Answer (score 3):

For the **current** directory `.`, you can use the `%P` directive to `-printf` as a workaround:

```
find . -type f ... -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0 ls -l
```

---

From `man find`:

> `-printf format` (`%P`)
>
> File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was
>   found removed.

Comment: This is the route I would take, or even reimplement all of `ls -l` with a suitable `-printf` argument string.

Comment: @tripleee I didn't think of implementing `ls -l` output with `-printf` itself, good point.

Answer (score 2):

**For `OSX find` only:**

Use `-execdir` option instead of `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name "sample[0-9]*?_bill[0-9]*?.pdf" -mtime 0 -execdir ls -l {} +
```

Also you can use `+` instead of `\;` for better efficiency

---

Above behavior is on `OSX find`. for `gnu find` use following script to get rid of `./`:

```
find . -type f -name "sample[0-9]*?_bill[0-9]*?.pdf" -mtime 0 \
-exec bash -c 'ls -l "${@#./}"' - '{}' +
```

Or you may use this loop on `find` with *process substitution*:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
    ls -l "${file#./}"
done < <(find . -type f -name "sample[0-9]*?_bill[0-9]*?.pdf" -mtime 0 -print0)
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava sir, IMHO still last field is having `./` in it as per OP, OP don't need it, apologies if I am missing here something.

Comment: Actually on my OSX I don't get `./` when I use `-execdir`

Comment: oh ok sure, when I run it, it is giving me `./` in my BASH system, that's why I commented, no worries.

Comment: I am still getting `./` as well :(

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I believe `gnu find` works differently, I have updated my answer for `gnu find` version

Comment: For gnu find, the -printf version is much better.